# Combination regex letters and digits

Tags: regex

I'm really stuck on this. How do I do a combination of letters and digits? If it contains digits, that's will be invalid.

I've tried this. This doesn't work...

```
(^[a-z])+(^[0-9])+
```

**example:**

```
abcd (valid)
abcd123 (invalid)
123abcd (invalid)
```

Comment: Digits and numbers are the same thing. Please clarify

Comment: @Barmar - oops I mean letters and digits

Comment: [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) is a good place to test regex and has helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will treat a string with digits as invalid:

```
^\D*$
```

`\D` matches everything that isn't a digit.

Answer (score -1):

You're explicitly saying "starts with one or more lowercase letters". Why would it work on a string that starts with numbers?

If you want it to work with either, combine using or `|`:

```
(^[a-z]|[0-9])+
```

Example here: http://regex101.com/r/eO7tD6/1

Also, if you're wanting to match the character sequence, you'll want the `+` inside the parens.

Comment: I'm the downvoter. I don't really have much to say, aside from that you clearly misread the question. You should delete this answer, read the question, and (if desired) post a new answer that actually answers it.

Comment: @ruakh "How do I do a combination of letters and digits?" -- what exactly did I misread?

Comment: You misread the list of examples. The OP gave one valid example and two invalid ones. Your regex accepts all three.

Comment: @ruakh Hmm. Maybe you're misunderstanding. Sounds to me like op was *frustrated* by the fact the last example doesn't match.

Comment: Clearly OP asked about combination of letters and digits but stated that `abcd` is valid which are `alpha` characters. If OP wanted to match more than `a-z` then that should be specified. Otherwise `^[a-z]+$` is correct ...

Comment: (By the way, the `+` in your regex is superfluous; it will not affect the match. But that's minor.)

Comment: Re: "Sounds to me like op was *frustrated* by the fact the last example doesn't match": Oh, I understand your thought-process, then. But I still think you're mistaken. Even before giving his/her own regex, the OP stated that "If it contains digits, that's will be invalid."

Comment: @ruakh Again, I interpreted that differently. I took that to mean that *currently* it will be invalid (which it will be, with ops original regex). Oh well.